# Remove listener on componentWillUnmount using static methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using static methods to implement my listener functions. Example:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  static heavyCalculation() { console.log('Calculating') }

  static listenerFunc() { console.log('Resize'); this.heavyCalculation() }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.constructor.listenerFunc, false)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.constructor.listenerFunc, false)
  }
}
```

The listener adds fine, however, when unmounting the component, the function doesn't seem to get removed, and still triggering my static method. I thought  `this.constructor.listenerFunc === this.constructor.listenerFunc` since it's a class method, but in my example it doesn't seem so. What am I missing?

### UPDATE

I updated my code. My listener function actually calls another `static` method `heavyCalculation`. This is where it mess things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it's my babel transpiler or React itself but I solved it using the classname. Here's my updated code:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  static heavyCalculation() { console.log('Calculating') }

  static listenerFunc() { 
    console.log('Resize')
    MyComponent.heavyCalculation()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.constructor.listenerFunc, false)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.constructor.listenerFunc, false)
  }
}
```

So instead of calling `this.heavyCalculation()` I used `MyComponent.heavyCalculation()`. Solves it.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument is mandatory.

See: [removeEventListener is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825493/removeeventlistener-is-not-working)

Also, make sure that you've bound `this` to your function.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.constructor.listenerFunc, false)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.constructor.listenerFunc, false)
}
```

`this.constructor.listenerFunc = this.constructor.listenerFunc.bind(this)`

See: [I can’t seem to reliably remove a listener using componentWillUnmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808808/i-can-t-seem-to-reliably-remove-a-listener-using-componentwillunmount?rq=1)

Comment: Oh sorry, I just assumed it worked without it, I do have the 3rd arg in my code, I was too lazy not to put it in the example..

Comment: My next guess would be that `this.constructor` is incorrect.  Why not use `this.listenerFunc`?

Comment: `this.contructor` is not needed i think

Comment: `this.constructor` is required, since you're not calling it from a static method.

Comment: Last guess, is that you need to `.bind(this)` since the value of `this` is different between `addEventListener ` and `removeEventListener `

Comment: Thanks for the helps @RaphaelRafatpanah I found the answer. Not sure if it's a Babel or React issue.